# Adding Custom permalink tags in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, permanent-generation

Basically what i want to achieve is to add a variable ?a=uk on the end of all the links of a wordpress blog
Ive tried various solutions that i have read with similar problems to no avail
im ideally after setting the permalinks to be %postname%/%a%

but my efforts to create %a% as a tag have been unsuccessful.

Ive been reading round for a few days now and cant seem to get anything to work and would appreciate anyones help in this matter

Comment: Is there any good reason for doing this ?

Comment: i need to pass the variable "a" through all the links

Comment: I understand that, but why ??

Comment: becuase we pass user locations through the query string

Comment: The content of your site change depending on this var ? How do you handle this ?

Comment: yes the variable is passed into a switch to change content

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10281/discussion-between-soju-and-dave-roach)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your permalink structure to this

%postname%/?a=uk

**Edit**: From your discussions, it seems that you don't have to modify the permalink structure at all, since external sites which are going to link to it will be including them automatically.

**Edit2**:

To automatically include the parameter in all the links from your page, you should hook into the get_permalink hook. You can't do it by changing the permalink structure.

Comment: i need the "uk" to be variable

Comment: From where will you be populating the value for this variable?

Comment: Manual linking such as www.somesite.com/wordpress/?a=something for example

Comment: Do you mean that the external sites that are going to link to your pages will include this parameter?

Comment: Then you don't have to edit your permalink structure. WordPress will ignore any parameters which you pass in addition to the actual permalink of the post. You can access the value of this variable either using $_GET['a'] or by analyzing your access log.

Comment: yes but i need to pass through the $_GET['a'] through the all the links of the site. and you cant put %postname%/?a=<?php echo $_GET['a']; ?>, so i need a way of passing the variable through

Comment: I need this too and I need those variables passed along with the $_REQUEST that is available to plugins... did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying all the wordpress links, you should use session or cookie to handle your users location.

EDIT :

- you should use a i18n plugin
- or you can easily modify all your links using javascript

Comment: Unfortunate need the variable in the query string encase the user bookmarks the link